# unable to get checkbox values

Tags: php, json, checkbox

I have the following code. I want to get only selected checkbox values but I get only last checkbox value. see what's wrong in my code.

```
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                            <h4>Select Jobwork</h4>

                               <table id="data-table" class="table table-hover jobworks-table table-responsive">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr style="background-color: #DDDD; color:firebrick;">
                                            <th><input type='checkbox' value="1" name="select_all" /></th>
                                            <th>JobWork Name</th>
                                            <th>Description</th>
                                            <th>Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($item as $key=>$value){
                                $decoded = json_decode($value['jobWorkJsonString']); ?>
                                       <?php foreach($decoded as $row){ ?>
                                            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                                <td><input type='checkbox' name="<?php echo $row->jobwork; ?>" /></td>
                                                <td style="padding-left:0px;"><?php echo $row->jobwork; ?><input type="hidden" name="jobwork_name" value="<?php echo $row->jobwork; ?>"></td>
                                                <td style="padding-left:0px;"><?php echo $row->description; ?><input type="hidden" name="jobwork_description" value="<?php echo $row->description; ?>"></td>
                                                <td style="padding-left:0px;"><?php echo $row->jobPrice; ?><input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row->jobPrice; ?>"></td>        
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            <br>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you submit multiple fields with the same name, then PHP will only put the last one into `$_POST` / `$_GET`.

The exception is when you end the name with `[]` in which case it will generate an array instead.

However, checkboxes are only successful controls when checked, so simply adding `[]` to the names will cause the association between each set of date to be lost.

Instead of submitting all the data about each *jobwork* (you aren't trying to *change* it, otherwise you wouldn't be using hidden inputs!), put *all* the data you *need* into the checkbox input. Look up the rest of the data on the server.

```
<td><input type='checkbox' name="jobwork[]" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row->id); ?>"/></td>
```

I've used `$row->id` as an example. I don't know how your data is structured on the server.

You will then be able to do:

```
foreach ($_POST['jobwork'] as $jobwork_id) {
    $row = look_up_jobwork_by_id($jobwork_id);
}
```

… only the checked checkboxes values will appear in that array.

Comment: in json string i don't have id.. & if i pass name value="<?= htmlspecialchars($row->jobwork); then it doesn't show selected values

Comment: @HarunAnwar — Quote: "I've used $row->id as an example. I don't know how your data is structured on the server."

Comment: i get the following output
jobwork] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

Answer (score 0):

You have issue in the first checkbox code.
Name is given as value, both names should be same for the checkbox, 
and get the request as an array

```
<?php foreach ($item as $key=>$value){
                                    $decoded = json_decode($value['jobWorkJsonString']); ?>
                                           <?php foreach($decoded as $row){ ?>
                                                <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                                    <td><input type='checkbox' name="jobwork"  value="<?php echo $row->jobwork; ?>" /></td>
                                                    <td style="padding-left:0px;"><?php echo $row->jobwork; ?><input type="hidden" name="jobwork_name" value="<?php echo $row->jobwork; ?>"></td>
                                                    <td style="padding-left:0px;"><?php echo $row->description; ?><input type="hidden" name="jobwork_description" value="<?php echo $row->description; ?>"></td>
                                                    <td style="padding-left:0px;"><?php echo $row->jobPrice; ?><input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $row->jobPrice; ?>"></td>        
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </tr>
                                        <?php } ?>
```

get the value of job_work as an `array`, you will get the selected job_work

Comment: I got blank array